# ASPEmail with UTF-8 produces scrambled characters

Tags: utf-8, asp-classic

Can anybody tell me, why this code is not working?
The mail gets sent, but the characters are scrambeled up.

"日本語" becomes "æ—¥æœ¬èªž"

"テスト　日本語 äöü" becomes "ãƒ†ã‚¹ãƒˆã€€æ—¥æœ¬èªž Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼"

```
<%

    Session.CodePage = 65001    ' UTF-8 code

%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>MAIL TESTER</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

<%

    strSubject = "日本語"
    strBody = "テスト　日本語 äöü"

    Set objEmail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")

    objEmail.Host = "..."
    objEmail.From = "..."
    objEmail.FromName = "..."
    objEmail.AddAddress "..."

    objEmail.Username = "..."
    objEmail.Password = "..."


    objEmail.CharSet = "UTF-8"
    objEmail.ContentTransferEncoding = "Quoted-Printable"
    objEmail.IsHTML = True

    objEmail.Subject = objEmail.EncodeHeader(strSubject, "UTF-8")
    objEmail.Body = strBody

    objEmail.Send


    Set objEmail = Nothing

%>

MAIL SENT.

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way: When I change the FromName to "日本語". That will be displayed correctly in my e-mail app! Strange. I remove the line: "Session.CodePage = 65001" and nothing changed. I tried many versions of this code, but nothing helped so far. Any idea?

Comment: I made the following change:
objEmail.Subject = objEmail.EncodeHeader(strSubject, "UTF-8")
to:
objEmail.Subject = strSubject
and now the subject displays correctly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add the following code on all the pages:

```
Session.CodePage = 65001
Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
```

or

```
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
```

and then in notepad++, I had to make sure that the files are saved with the "Encode in UTF-8". My pages were saved as "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM". I don't know why they were saved like that, but that's how it was.