# Persits.Mailsender UTF-8 encoding does not work when sending an email

Tags: email, asp-classic

I am trying to send an email containing Unicode characters with a `Persits.Mailsender` object in classic ASP

unicodeCharacters =  Pls help me(or whichever characters you prefer)

```
Set Mailer = CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
Mailer.Host = HOST_STRING
Mailer.FromName = sFromAddress
Mailer.From = sFromAddress

Mailer.ContentTransferEncoding = "Quoted-Printable"
Mailer.CharSet = "UTF-8"
Mailer.AddAddress "email@email.com", "email@email.com"
Mailer.Subject = Mailer.EncodeHeader( sSubject, "UTF-8")
Mailer.Body = unicodeCharacters
Mailer.Send
```

This matches everything I've found online regarding sending a UFT8 encoded email using a `persits.mailsender` object so any help is appreciated

EDIT: I attempted the proposed change in the comments and it did not fix the emails encoding, it also broke the UTF-8 encoding on the webpage this code is called from

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASPEmail with UTF-8 produces scrambled characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305818/aspemail-with-utf-8-produces-scrambled-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%
' change to address of your own SMTP server
strHost = "smtp.myisp.net"
' Enable UTF-8 -> Unicode translation for form items
Session.CodePage = 65001 ' UTF-8 code

If Request("Send") <> "" Then
   Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
   ' enter valid SMTP host
   Mail.Host = strHost

   Mail.From = "info@aspemail.com" ' From address
   Mail.FromName = Mail.EncodeHeader(Request("FromName"), "utf-8")
   Mail.AddAddress Request("To")

   ' message subject
   Mail.Subject = Mail.EncodeHeader( Request("Subject"), "utf-8")

   ' message body
   Mail.Body = Request("Body")

   ' UTF-8 parameters
   Mail.CharSet = "UTF-8"
   Mail.ContentTransferEncoding = "Quoted-Printable"
   Mail.Send ' send message
   Response.Write "Message sent to " & Request("To")
End If
%>
```

review the official website for more information.
http://www.aspemail.com/manual_06.html